# Best Practice setup for Parameter Sets

Tags: powershell, parameters

I'm trying to setup parameter sets but I'm unsure if that's the best practice approch to what I'm trying to do.  The setup I'm looking for is the following:

```
$FolderSetup - Not Manditory.  [ValidateSet("Yes", "No"] Default is "No"
    If "Yes" is used, then no following parameters should be able to be selected
$OSVersion - Manditory.  [ValidateSet("2008SP2", "2008R2", "2012R2", "2016", "All")].  
    If "All" is used, then no following parameters should be able to be selected

$InputFile - Not Manditory - User inputs location of file
$OutputFolder - Not Manditory.  - User inputs desired output location
    $InputFile must be used before $OutputFolder can be used.
```

Examples:

```
SinglePackage -FolderSetup 'Yes'
    #No Other Parameters can be used
SinglePackage -OSVersion 'All'
    #No Other Parameters can be used
SinglePackage -OSVersion '2008SP2'
SinglePackage -OSVersion '2008SP2' -InputFile 'C:\Temp\MyFile.txt'
SinglePackage -OSVersion '2008SP2' -InputFile 'C:\Temp\MyFile.txt' -OutputFolder 'C:\Temp\MyFolder'
SinglePackage -OSVersion '2008SP2' -OutputFolder 'C:\Temp\MyFolder'
    #Not Allowed.  Must have -InputFile if using -OutputFolder
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Please provide some examples of how your script would be called.

Comment: Based off what iu am seeing you cant do that in the param settings. You will need to do that in the function throwing errors

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I added examples.  Please let me know if I should try explaining it further.

Comment: @ArcSet So that's not possible.  Ok.  Thanks ArcSet.  That's what I was wondering.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do params you asked for...

```
Function TEST(){
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)]
        [switch]$FolderSetup,

        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$false)]
        [ValidateSet("2008SP2", "2008R2", "2012R2", "2016", "All")]
        [string]$OSVersion,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="InputFiles", Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$InputFile,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="InputFiles", Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$OutputFolder
    )

}
```

Comment: Makes more sense to have `$FolderSetup` as a `[switch]`

Comment: he's looking for best practices, so it's worth including the 'correct' way to do it?

Comment: Thanks @ArcSet, but you seemed to have overlooked a few things. Please look at the examples I listed.  I hope they help explain what it is I'm looking for or if what I'm looking for is even possible.  `$FolderSetup` is not mandatory, but if it is set to `Yes` it is the only parameters that can be used.  `InputFile` is mandatory only if `$OutputFolder` is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this would be to declare the parameter block as follows:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="Folder")]
    [switch]$FolderSetup,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="AllVersions")]
    [Alias("AllOS")]
    [switch]$All,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="OSSpecific")]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="IOFolders")]
    [ValidateSet("2008SP2","2008R2", "2102R2", "2016")]
    [string]$OSVersion,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="IOFolders")]
    [string]$InputFolder,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="IOFolders")]
    [string]$OutputFolder
)
```

This forces the call to be in one of the valid forms you gave above, and prohibits the invalid combinations. If it can't figure out which set of parameters is being used, it will throw an error saying so - but that's a guarantee that an invalid combination of parameters was attempted.

It does have the constraint that you can't use `-OSVersion "All"`; use `-All` or `-AllOS` instead.